# Common Android DatePicker widget

Tags: android, datepicker

How do i implement a common android datepicker widget, preferable in a widgets package, to be used in several layouts in my app. The value of the date selected is to be passed as a String variable to be saved in a database. I don't want to use the below code in every activity that serves a layout that has a DatePicker.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    //UI References
    private EditText etxtDate;

    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDailog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        fromDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_fromdate);    
        fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();

    }

    private void setDateTimeField() {
        etxt.setOnClickListener(this);

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

       }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == etxtDate) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create this class for your date picker dialog

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

OnDateSetListener dateSetListener;
private int year = 0;
private int month = 0;
private int day = 0;

public DatePickerFragment(OnDateSetListener dateSetListener) {
    this.dateSetListener = dateSetListener;
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}

public DatePickerFragment(OnDateSetListener dateSetListener, String date) {
    this.dateSetListener = dateSetListener;
    // Use the Given date as the default date in the picker
    int parsedDate[] = new int[3];
    int itterator = 0;
    for (String retval : date.split("/")) {
        parsedDate[itterator] = Integer.parseInt(retval);
        itterator++;
    }
    day = parsedDate[0];
    month = parsedDate[1] - 1;
    year = parsedDate[2];
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), dateSetListener, year,
            month, day);
}
```

create the object of this class and call you have to create your date listener for every activity or fragment you want

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {

            //your action after the date is selected
        }

    };
```

then call the date picker using your listener like this

```
datePicker = new DatePickerFragment(fromDateSetListener);
```

or

```
datePicker = new DatePickerFragment(fromDateSetListener,date);
//date is the string which will be shown on the date picker dialog by default
```

now invoke the date picker dialog

```
datePicker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Comment: Vishwajit, thanks. Cannot resolve symbol 'PlayerApplication'.

Comment: i am really sorry that is my code i have updated it you can check it now

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Create a parent activity and include this code in that activity.
2. Create new activity (every activity that serves a layout that has a DatePicker) by extending this parent activity.

This way you would be able to access the same code in child activities!